# How to store circular document inside table?

Tags: database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to NoSQL database design. For my application I have two entities to store in database. I will use JSON-like notation to represent structure.

```
User {
   id: Uuid,
   telegram_user_id: int64
   room: Optional<Room>,
   nickname: String,
}

Room {
   id: Uuid,
   first_user: User
   second_user: Optional<User>
}
```

So I basically have `User` which can create and join a `Room`. When `User` creates room he's already joined inside is.

I need to do several things.

1. Create a new User without room.
2. Attach a room to User.
3. Easily find User by it's `telegram_user_id`.
4. Add `Room.second_user` when another user joins the room, when I have `Room.id` and `User.telegram_user_id`.
5. Find `Room.second_user`, when I have `User.telegram_user_id`.

Most queries will be when querying `User` by it's `telegram_id` and when finding second user inside a room, using first user `telegram_user_id`.

I don't understand how to design it well for DynamoDB. 
I could possibly use relational data model and do several queries. In that example `User.room` will be just `Room.id` and `Room.first_user`,`Room.second_user` will be `User.id`.

To find second user, by first user `telegram_user_id` I would have to do several queries.

1. Finding first User
2. Using a `User.room` as partition key to find `Room`
3. Then finding second `User` by id in `Room.second_user`.

But it feels not right to do it with several independent queries.

But I don't know how to implement my requirements well without relational data model.

How to design this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should design base on Adjacency List Design Pattern: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-adjacency-graphs.html

Partition Key (PK) | Sort Key (SK) | data | remain_attributes ....

(1) USER#telegram_user_id1 | USER#detail | nickname1 | id1

(2) USER#telegram_user_id1 | ROOM#uuid1 | joinedAtTime

(3) USER#telegram_user_id1 | USER#second#telegram_user_id2 | ROOM#uuid1 | joinedAtTime

(4) USER#telegram_user_id2 | USER#detail | nickname2 | id2

(5) ROOM#uuid1 | ROOM#detail | createdAtTime

1. Create user without room: create record (1), (4)
2. Create a room: as record (5) and attach first user to room as record (2)
3. Find an user, query: **PK=USER#telegram_user_id1**, **SK=USER#detail**
4. Attach second user to room as record (3)
5. Find second users by first user (e.g: user telegram_user_id1), query: **PK=USER#telegram_user_id1**, **SK=begins_with(USER#second)**

Hope this help you.